# How to play one game in one PC at same time but with two different players

Tags: windows, gaming, windows-11

I have Minecraft on my PC, And I have a brother (10 years old). He wants to play Minecraft with me on my server.

But I have only one powerful PC that can run Minecraft that is running Windows 11 2200, 12 GB, Intel i5 processor.

I also have another PC, but it is ten years old and runs Windows XP with 2GB RAM.

I want to play with my brother simultaneously using two screens, two keyboards and mouse. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the tool [Universal Splitscreen](https://universalsplitscreen.github.io/). This tool will allow you to play multiple instances of the same game on a single computer, using multiple controllers/sharing keyboards and mice.

They have a guide on setting up Minecraft for your scenario as well, indicating a requirement for a custom launcher, located here: https://universalsplitscreen.github.io/docs/guides/minecraft/

(note: I have not tried this application myself, it just seemed like your best bet)

Comment: Thank you . I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

You'd be fine running two apps on two screens, but your mouse & keyboard can only interact with one at a time. Adding another mouse & keyboard would not help.

Comment: Could you use a VM or something similar and bind the second mouse and keyboard to that?

Comment: Even if you could, you'd still have the issue as to which app was frontmost.

Answer (score 0):

You can run vm like Virtualbox and add USB devices to that. Not best performance, but it should do.

As alternative there are multiseat apps, like ibik ASTER. Best performance, but costs some money.